# How do I unlock the doors that are “locked from the other side” in Resident Evil?

Tags: resident-evil-2002

I’ve completed *Resident Evil* multiple times and noticed there were a couple rooms I never went into. These are the ones that say they are “locked from the other side” in the main hallway and the first door in the hall next to the dining room. Is there any way to get into these rooms?

I’m playing the 2002 (GameCube) version.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, these doors are intentionally placed like this to add more mystery to the game. enjoy